# How can I make separator in Tkinter fill whole window height?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to place separator that goes from top of the window to bottom on specific place with `.place()` function. When I do it like that, separator is just a little dot. I managed to do it with `.pack()` function but then it's not on desired place. I searched on internet but I couldn't find solution that uses `.place()`, only `.pack()` and `.grid()`.
[It's just a dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0buw3.png) instead of line from top to bottom.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

App = Tk()

ttk.Separator(App, orient=VERTICAL).place(x=275, y=0)

App.mainloop()
```

Is it possible to do it with `.place()` and if it is (probably is) how?

I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: `place(..., relheight=1.0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I know of is to specify `height=` in pixels on `place()` call:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

App = Tk()
App.geometry('1000x100')

ttk.Separator(App, orient=VERTICAL).place(x=275, y=0, height=100)

App.mainloop()
```

It would also be possible to pair it with automatical height detection:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

App = Tk()
App.update()

ttk.Separator(App, orient=VERTICAL).place(x=50, y=0, height=App.winfo_height())

App.mainloop()
```

And, to update dynamically:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

App = Tk()

sep = ttk.Separator(App, orient=VERTICAL)
sep.place(x=50, y=0, height=App.winfo_height())

App.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: sep.place(x=50, y=0, height=App.winfo_height()))

App.mainloop()
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you. I didn't know I can specify height in `.place()`

Comment: it has one problem - it doesn't change separator's height when window change height. But `relheight=1.0` instead of `height=` resolves this problem.

Comment: @furas here, so you can use px expressions

Comment: Why don't just use `relheight=1.0` instead?

Comment: So you can write exact pixel expressions (100px from the bottom etc.) if you need those. You probably would.

Comment: You can combine `relheight` and `height` to have the same effect: `place(x=50, y=0, relheight=1.0, height=-100)`.